# Adding layout in Fragment results in NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-fragments

I have encountered a problem in my Android application.  When I try to add a view in my Fragment for my ListView, the app crashes.  Here is my LogCat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.foodsaver2.DatabaseFillerFragment$3.onItemClick(DatabaseFillerFragment.java:912)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my code:

```
  LinearLayout customerLayout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.customerLayout);
  if(customerLayout == null){
       //Inflate the Customer Information View
       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
       LinearLayout leftLayout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.rightLayout);
       View customerInfo = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.foodinfo, leftLayout, false);
       leftLayout.addView(customerInfo); //It crashes on this line!
  }
```

I have checked SO and Google for a while now, and I am starting to get frustrated.  Any help regarding this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot wrong here.

1. You get an instance of LayoutInflater but never use it
2. You assign leftLayout to the view with id R.id.rightLayout
3. You're trying to add a view to a ViewGroup that it's already been added to

Try the following:

---

```
LinearLayout customerLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.customerLayout);
if (customerLayout == null) { 
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rightLayout);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.foodinfo, leftLayout);
}
```

---

`inflate(int, ViewGroup)` and `inflate(int, ViewGroup, boolean)` handle adding the View to the parent ViewGroup automatically (unless the 3rd boolean parameter is set to false). It's possible that `leftLayout` resolved to null, in which case you should ensure that `view` contains a View with id `@id/rightLayout`.